# Using ex in init scripts

Tags: linux, debian, bash, vim, init

I'm using ex to modify configuration files from an /etc/init.d/CONFIG script.

I'm using debian squeeze (updated yesterday)

My problem is:
It's impossible to start ex / vi in init scripts with the vi / ex package of the current squeeze system.
There is no error message - the prompt just stops but can be freed with STRG-C.

It worked until yersterday with packages from squeeze / 3 month ago.

My question is why? And what can I do to solve this?

**Edit1**:
There is only a script trying to get configs from USB and configuring services.

**Edit2**:
A sample of what I'm doing:

```
# get usb stick's mount point
...
# get config from stick
...
# edit config file
ex ${PREFIX}/etc/mysql/my.cnf -c '%s/^datadir.*$/datadir = /usr/local/mysql/data' -c'wq!'
# change that might fail and is allowed to fail
( ex ${PREFIX}/etc/ntp.conf -c '%s/^driftfile.*$/driftfile \/media\/bootfs\/config\/system\/ntp.drift/g' -c '/^server/d' -c '/^server/d' -c '/^server/d' -c '/^server/d' -c'wq!' ) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Edit3** - some dpkg.log entries (only upgrades):

```
2010-08-22 17:43:12 upgrade locales 2.10.2-6 2.11.2-2
2010-08-22 17:43:13 upgrade libc-bin 2.10.2-6 2.11.2-2
2010-08-22 17:43:17 upgrade libc6 2.10.2-6 2.11.2-2
2010-08-22 17:43:27 upgrade libc6-i686 2.10.2-6 2.11.2-2
2010-08-22 17:43:27 upgrade libc6-dev 2.10.2-6 2.11.2-2
2010-08-22 17:43:28 upgrade libc-dev-bin 2.10.2-6 2.11.2-2
2010-08-22 17:43:29 upgrade debconf-english 1.5.32 1.5.35
2010-08-22 17:43:34 upgrade debconf 1.5.32 1.5.35
2010-08-22 17:43:37 upgrade linux-libc-dev 2.6.32-9 2.6.32-18
2010-08-22 17:43:38 upgrade libgomp1 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:38 upgrade cpp-4.4 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:38 upgrade binutils 2.20.1-5 2.20.1-12
2010-08-22 17:43:39 upgrade gcc-4.4-base 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:42 upgrade libgcc1 1:4.4.2-9 1:4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:44 upgrade gcc-4.4 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:44 upgrade g++-4.4 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:45 upgrade libstdc++6-4.4-dev 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:46 upgrade libgfortran3 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:46 upgrade libstdc++6 4.4.2-9 4.4.4-8
2010-08-22 17:43:48 upgrade libxapian15 1.0.19-1 1.0.20-2
2010-08-22 17:43:48 upgrade libsqlite3-0 3.6.23.1-1 3.7.0-1.1
2010-08-22 17:43:49 upgrade aptitude 0.6.1.5-3 0.6.3-3
2010-08-22 17:43:53 upgrade libfreetype6-dev 2.3.11-1 2.4.2-1
2010-08-22 17:43:53 upgrade libfreetype6 2.3.11-1 2.4.2-1
2010-08-22 17:43:53 upgrade libpcre3 7.8-3 8.02-1.1
2010-08-22 17:43:54 upgrade libselinux1 2.0.94-1 2.0.96-1
2010-08-22 17:43:58 upgrade libglib2.0-0 2.24.0-1 2.24.1-1
2010-08-22 17:43:58 upgrade libpopt0 1.15-1 1.16-1
2010-08-22 17:43:58 upgrade pkg-config 0.22-1 0.25-1
2010-08-22 17:43:58 upgrade libfontconfig1-dev 2.8.0-2 2.8.0-2.1
2010-08-22 17:43:59 upgrade ttf-dejavu-core 2.30-2 2.31-1
2010-08-22 17:43:59 upgrade libfontconfig1 2.8.0-2 2.8.0-2.1
2010-08-22 17:43:59 upgrade fontconfig-config 2.8.0-2 2.8.0-2.1
2010-08-22 17:44:00 upgrade libgtk2.0-common 2.20.0-3 2.20.1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:03 upgrade libavahi-common-data 0.6.25-3 0.6.26-1
2010-08-22 17:44:03 upgrade libavahi-common3 0.6.25-3 0.6.26-1
2010-08-22 17:44:03 upgrade libdbus-1-3 1.2.24-1 1.2.24-3
2010-08-22 17:44:05 upgrade libavahi-client3 0.6.25-3 0.6.26-1
2010-08-22 17:44:05 upgrade libcomerr2 1.41.11-1 1.41.12-2
2010-08-22 17:44:16 upgrade libk5crypto3 1.8.1+dfsg-2 1.8.3+dfsg~beta1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:16 upgrade libgssapi-krb5-2 1.8.1+dfsg-2 1.8.3+dfsg~beta1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:16 upgrade libkrb5-3 1.8.1+dfsg-2 1.8.3+dfsg~beta1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:16 upgrade libkrb5support0 1.8.1+dfsg-2 1.8.3+dfsg~beta1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:16 upgrade libcups2 1.4.3-1 1.4.4-2
2010-08-22 17:44:17 upgrade libjpeg62-dev 6b-16.1 6b1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:17 upgrade libjpeg62 6b-16.1 6b1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:17 upgrade fontconfig 2.8.0-2 2.8.0-2.1
2010-08-22 17:44:43 upgrade libpango1.0-common 1.28.0-1 1.28.1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:43 upgrade libxrender1 1:0.9.5-2 1:0.9.6-1
2010-08-22 17:44:43 upgrade libpango1.0-0 1.28.0-1 1.28.1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:44 upgrade libpng12-dev 1.2.43-1 1.2.44-1
2010-08-22 17:44:44 upgrade libpng12-0 1.2.43-1 1.2.44-1
2010-08-22 17:44:44 upgrade libtiff4 3.9.2-3+b1 3.9.4-2
2010-08-22 17:44:44 upgrade libxext6 2:1.1.1-3 2:1.1.2-1
2010-08-22 17:44:44 upgrade libxfixes3 1:4.0.4-2 1:4.0.5-1
2010-08-22 17:44:45 upgrade libxcomposite1 1:0.4.1-1 1:0.4.2-1
2010-08-22 17:44:45 upgrade libxdamage1 1:1.1.2-1 1:1.1.3-1
2010-08-22 17:44:45 upgrade libxml2-dev 2.7.7.dfsg-2 2.7.7.dfsg-4
2010-08-22 17:44:45 upgrade libxml2 2.7.7.dfsg-2 2.7.7.dfsg-4
2010-08-22 17:44:45 upgrade shared-mime-info 0.71-1 0.71-3
2010-08-22 17:44:46 upgrade libgtk2.0-0 2.20.0-3 2.20.1-1
2010-08-22 17:44:46 upgrade liblcms1 1.18.dfsg-1.2+b1 1.18.dfsg-1.2+b2
2010-08-22 17:44:47 upgrade ufraw 0.16-1+b1 0.16-3+b1
2010-08-22 17:44:47 upgrade exiv2 0.19-1 0.20-2
2010-08-22 17:44:51 upgrade gcc-4.3 4.3.4-8 4.3.5-2
2010-08-22 17:44:51 upgrade cpp-4.3 4.3.4-8 4.3.5-2
2010-08-22 17:44:52 upgrade gcc-4.3-base 4.3.4-8 4.3.5-2
2010-08-22 17:44:56 upgrade base-files 5.3 5.9
2010-08-22 17:45:01 upgrade coreutils 7.4-2 8.5-1
2010-08-22 17:45:08 upgrade debianutils 3.2.2 3.4
2010-08-22 17:45:11 upgrade libpam0g 1.1.1-2 1.1.1-3
2010-08-22 17:45:14 upgrade sed 4.2.1-6 4.2.1-7
2010-08-22 17:45:17 upgrade lsb-base 3.2-23 3.2-23.1
2010-08-22 17:45:18 upgrade libpam-modules 1.1.1-2 1.1.1-3
2010-08-22 17:45:23 upgrade libpam-runtime 1.1.1-2 1.1.1-3
2010-08-22 17:45:26 upgrade grub-pc 1.98-1 1.98+20100804-2
2010-08-22 17:45:26 upgrade grub-common 1.98-1 1.98+20100804-2
2010-08-22 17:45:27 upgrade dpkg 1.15.5.6 1.15.7.2
2010-08-22 17:45:31 upgrade cron 3.0pl1-109 3.0pl1-114
2010-08-22 17:45:34 upgrade libudev0 151-3 160-1
2010-08-22 17:45:34 upgrade libusb-0.1-4 2:0.1.12-14 2:0.1.12-15
2010-08-22 17:45:37 upgrade libuuid1 2.16.2-0 2.17.2-3.1
2010-08-22 17:45:39 upgrade libblkid1 2.16.2-0 2.17.2-3.1
2010-08-22 17:45:40 upgrade tzdata 2010h-1 2010j-1
2010-08-22 17:45:44 upgrade insserv 1.12.0-14 1.14.0-2
2010-08-22 17:45:46 upgrade sysvinit-utils 2.87dsf-10 2.88dsf-11
2010-08-22 17:45:48 upgrade sysv-rc 2.87dsf-10 2.88dsf-11
2010-08-22 17:45:51 upgrade mount 2.16.2-0 2.17.2-3.1
2010-08-22 17:45:55 upgrade initscripts 2.87dsf-10 2.88dsf-11
2010-08-22 17:46:01 upgrade util-linux 2.16.2-0 2.17.2-3.1
2010-08-22 17:46:08 upgrade udev 151-3 160-1
2010-08-22 17:46:09 upgrade dmsetup 2:1.02.45-1 2:1.02.48-2
2010-08-22 17:46:09 upgrade libdevmapper1.02.1 2:1.02.45-1 2:1.02.48-2
2010-08-22 17:46:09 upgrade gettext-base 0.17-10 0.18.1.1-1
2010-08-22 17:46:09 upgrade dash 0.5.5.1-3 0.5.5.1-6
2010-08-22 17:46:13 upgrade diffutils 1:2.9-4 1:3.0-1
2010-08-22 17:46:16 upgrade e2fslibs 1.41.11-1 1.41.12-2
2010-08-22 17:46:18 upgrade e2fsprogs 1.41.11-1 1.41.12-2
2010-08-22 17:46:21 upgrade perl-modules 5.10.1-12 5.10.1-14
2010-08-22 17:46:23 upgrade perl-debug 5.10.1-12 5.10.1-14
2010-08-22 17:46:25 upgrade perl 5.10.1-12 5.10.1-14
2010-08-22 17:46:27 upgrade libperl5.10 5.10.1-12 5.10.1-14
2010-08-22 17:46:28 upgrade perl-base 5.10.1-12 5.10.1-14
2010-08-22 17:46:31 upgrade libsepol1 2.0.40-2 2.0.41-1
2010-08-22 17:46:34 upgrade sysvinit 2.87dsf-10 2.88dsf-11
2010-08-22 17:46:37 upgrade tar 1.23-1 1.23-2.1
2010-08-22 17:46:39 upgrade bsdutils 1:2.16.2-0 1:2.17.2-3.1
2010-08-22 17:46:42 upgrade module-init-tools 3.12~pre2-3 3.12-1
2010-08-22 17:46:43 upgrade klibc-utils 1.5.17-4 1.5.18-1
2010-08-22 17:46:43 upgrade libklibc 1.5.17-4 1.5.18-1
2010-08-22 17:46:43 upgrade cpio 2.11-2 2.11-4
2010-08-22 17:46:44 upgrade initramfs-tools 0.93.4 0.98
2010-08-22 17:46:53 upgrade mysql-common 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 17:46:53 upgrade mysql-server 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 17:46:53 upgrade libdbi-perl 1.609-1 1.612-1
2010-08-22 17:46:54 upgrade libmysqlclient-dev 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 17:46:55 upgrade libmysqlclient16 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 17:46:56 upgrade libdbd-mysql-perl 4.013-1 4.016-1
2010-08-22 17:46:56 upgrade readline-common 6.1-1 6.1-3
2010-08-22 17:47:02 upgrade libreadline6 6.1-1 6.1-3
2010-08-22 17:47:03 upgrade libwrap0-dev 7.6.q-18 7.6.q-19
2010-08-22 17:47:04 upgrade libwrap0 7.6.q-18 7.6.q-19
2010-08-22 17:47:04 upgrade mysql-client-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 17:47:09 upgrade mysql-server-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 17:47:13 upgrade libssl-dev 0.9.8n-1 0.9.8o-1
2010-08-22 17:47:14 upgrade libssl0.9.8 0.9.8n-1 0.9.8o-1
2010-08-22 17:47:15 upgrade dhcp3-client 3.1.3-2 4.1.1-P1-9
2010-08-22 17:47:15 upgrade netbase 4.40 4.42
2010-08-22 17:47:16 upgrade libattr1 1:2.4.44-1 1:2.4.44-2
2010-08-22 19:02:48 upgrade mysql-server-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 19:02:53 upgrade libcap2 1:2.17-2 1:2.19-3
2010-08-22 19:02:53 upgrade ntp 1:4.2.6+dfsg-1 1:4.2.6.p2+dfsg-1
2010-08-22 19:02:54 upgrade dbus 1.2.24-1 1.2.24-3
2010-08-22 19:02:54 upgrade dbus-x11 1.2.24-1 1.2.24-3
2010-08-22 19:02:54 upgrade x11-common 1:7.5+5 1:7.5+6
2010-08-22 19:02:55 upgrade libdrm2 2.4.18-5 2.4.18-6
2010-08-22 19:02:56 upgrade libdrm-intel1 2.4.18-5 2.4.18-6
2010-08-22 19:02:56 upgrade libdrm-radeon1 2.4.18-5 2.4.18-6
2010-08-22 19:02:56 upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri 7.7.1-1 7.7.1-4
2010-08-22 19:02:59 upgrade libgl1-mesa-glx 7.7.1-1 7.7.1-4
2010-08-22 19:02:59 upgrade libxtst6 2:1.1.0-2 2:1.1.0-3
2010-08-22 19:02:59 upgrade cpp 4:4.4.2-3 4:4.4.4-2
2010-08-22 21:59:51 upgrade mysql-server-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 21:59:57 upgrade x11-utils 7.5+3 7.5+4
2010-08-22 21:59:58 upgrade x11-xkb-utils 7.5+2 7.5+5
2010-08-22 21:59:58 upgrade gpgv 1.4.10-2 1.4.10-4
2010-08-22 22:01:33 upgrade linux-image-2.6-686 2.6.32+25 2.6.32+28
2010-08-22 22:01:48 upgrade gnupg 1.4.10-2 1.4.10-4
2010-08-22 22:01:53 upgrade libacl1 2.2.49-2 2.2.49-3
2010-08-22 22:01:55 upgrade liblzma2 4.999.9beta+20100307-1 4.999.9beta+20100713-1
2010-08-22 22:01:57 upgrade libss2 1.41.11-1 1.41.12-2
2010-08-22 22:01:59 upgrade xz-utils 4.999.9beta+20100307-1 4.999.9beta+20100713-1
2010-08-22 22:02:01 upgrade bsdmainutils 8.0.10 8.0.13
2010-08-22 22:02:02 upgrade dhcp3-server 3.1.3-2 4.1.1-P1-9
2010-08-22 22:02:02 upgrade dhcp3-common 3.1.3-2 4.1.1-P1-9
2010-08-22 22:02:03 upgrade groff-base 1.20.1-9 1.20.1-10
2010-08-22 22:02:03 upgrade iproute 20100224-3 20100519-3
2010-08-22 22:02:04 upgrade iptables 1.4.6-2 1.4.8-3
2010-08-22 22:02:04 upgrade iputils-ping 3:20100214-1 3:20100418-2
2010-08-22 22:02:05 upgrade libtasn1-3 2.5-1 2.7-1
2010-08-22 22:02:05 upgrade logrotate 3.7.8-5 3.7.8-6
2010-08-22 22:02:05 upgrade man-db 2.5.7-2 2.5.7-3
2010-08-22 22:02:06 upgrade procps 1:3.2.8-8 1:3.2.8-9
2010-08-22 22:02:06 upgrade traceroute 1:2.0.13-5 1:2.0.15-1
2010-08-22 22:02:07 upgrade vim-tiny 2:7.2.330-1 2:7.2.445+hg~cb94c42c0e1a-1
2010-08-22 22:02:08 upgrade vim 2:7.2.330-1 2:7.2.445+hg~cb94c42c0e1a-1
2010-08-22 22:02:08 upgrade vim-runtime 2:7.2.330-1 2:7.2.445+hg~cb94c42c0e1a-1
2010-08-22 22:02:13 upgrade vim-common 2:7.2.330-1 2:7.2.445+hg~cb94c42c0e1a-1
2010-08-22 22:02:13 upgrade bash-completion 1:1.1-3 1:1.2-2
2010-08-22 22:02:14 upgrade file 5.04-2 5.04-5
2010-08-22 22:02:14 upgrade libmagic1 5.04-2 5.04-5
2010-08-22 22:02:14 upgrade ftp 0.17-21 0.17-23
2010-08-22 22:02:15 upgrade pciutils 1:3.1.7-3 1:3.1.7-4
2010-08-22 22:02:15 upgrade libpci3 1:3.1.7-3 1:3.1.7-4
2010-08-22 22:02:15 upgrade m4 1.4.13-3 1.4.14-3
2010-08-22 22:02:15 upgrade openssh-server 1:5.3p1-3 1:5.5p1-4
2010-08-22 22:02:16 upgrade openssh-client 1:5.3p1-3 1:5.5p1-4
2010-08-22 22:02:17 upgrade python2.6 2.6.5-1 2.6.6~rc1-1
2010-08-22 22:02:19 upgrade python2.6-minimal 2.6.5-1 2.6.6~rc1-1
2010-08-22 22:02:20 upgrade apache2 2.2.15-3 2.2.16-1
2010-08-22 22:02:20 upgrade apache2-mpm-prefork 2.2.15-3 2.2.16-1
2010-08-22 22:02:26 upgrade apache2.2-common 2.2.15-3 2.2.16-1
2010-08-22 22:02:26 upgrade apache2.2-bin 2.2.15-3 2.2.16-1
2010-08-22 22:02:27 upgrade apache2-utils 2.2.15-3 2.2.16-1
2010-08-22 22:02:27 upgrade libapache2-mod-python 3.3.1-9 3.3.1-9+b1
2010-08-22 22:02:28 upgrade python-support 1.0.7 1.0.9
2010-08-22 22:02:28 upgrade lsb-release 3.2-23 3.2-23.1
2010-08-22 22:02:28 upgrade python2.5 2.5.5-2 2.5.5-6
2010-08-22 22:02:30 upgrade python2.5-minimal 2.5.5-2 2.5.5-6
2010-08-22 22:02:31 upgrade python-minimal 2.5.4-9 2.6.5-11
2010-08-22 22:02:31 upgrade python 2.5.4-9 2.6.5-11
2010-08-22 22:02:32 upgrade python-apt 0.7.94.2 0.7.96.1
2010-08-22 22:02:33 upgrade tcpd 7.6.q-18 7.6.q-19
2010-08-22 22:02:33 upgrade w3m 0.5.2-4 0.5.2-9
2010-08-22 22:02:34 upgrade whois 5.0.2 5.0.7
2010-08-22 22:02:34 upgrade acpid 1:2.0.3-1 1:2.0.6-1
2010-08-22 22:02:34 upgrade acpi-support-base 0.133-2 0.137-3
2010-08-22 22:02:35 upgrade python-xapian 1.0.19-1 1.0.20-1
2010-08-22 22:02:35 upgrade python-debian 0.1.16 0.1.18
2010-08-22 22:02:36 upgrade apt-xapian-index 0.30 0.38
2010-08-22 22:02:36 upgrade autoconf 2.65-4 2.67-2
2010-08-22 22:02:37 upgrade git-core 1:1.7.0-1 1:1.7.1-1.1
2010-08-22 22:02:37 upgrade libcurl3-gnutls 7.20.0-3 7.21.0-1
2010-08-22 22:02:37 upgrade libdigest-sha1-perl 2.12-1 2.13-1
2010-08-22 22:02:38 upgrade autopoint 0.17-10 0.18.1.1-1
2010-08-22 22:02:39 upgrade gcc 4:4.4.2-3 4:4.4.4-2
2010-08-22 22:02:39 upgrade g++ 4:4.4.2-3 4:4.4.4-2
2010-08-22 22:02:39 upgrade dpkg-dev 1.15.5.6 1.15.7.2
2010-08-22 22:02:40 upgrade build-essential 11.4 11.5
2010-08-22 22:02:40 upgrade busybox 1:1.14.2-2 1:1.17.1-2
2010-08-22 22:02:40 upgrade console-data 2:1.10-2 2:1.10-3
2010-08-22 22:02:41 upgrade keyboard-configuration 1.51 1.55
2010-08-22 22:02:42 upgrade console-setup 1.51 1.55
2010-08-22 22:02:42 upgrade cryptsetup 2:1.1.0-2.1 2:1.1.3-3
2010-08-22 22:02:42 upgrade html2text 1.3.2a-14 1.3.2a-15
2010-08-22 22:02:43 upgrade debhelper 7.4.17 8.0.0
2010-08-22 22:02:43 upgrade dialog 1.1-20100119-2 1.1-20100428-1
2010-08-22 22:02:44 upgrade firmware-linux-free 2.6.32-9 2.6.32-18
2010-08-22 22:02:44 upgrade firmware-linux-nonfree 0.23 0.26
2010-08-22 22:02:45 upgrade gettext 0.17-10 0.18.1.1-1
2010-08-22 22:02:46 upgrade ghostscript 8.71~dfsg-4 8.71~dfsg2-4
2010-08-22 22:02:48 upgrade ghostscript-x 8.71~dfsg-4 8.71~dfsg2-4
2010-08-22 22:02:48 upgrade libcupsimage2 1.4.3-1 1.4.4-2
2010-08-22 22:02:49 upgrade libpaper1 1.1.23+nmu2 1.1.24
2010-08-22 22:02:49 upgrade libgs8 8.71~dfsg-4 8.71~dfsg2-4
2010-08-22 22:02:49 upgrade gsfonts 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.2
2010-08-22 22:03:08 upgrade gs-common 8.71~dfsg-4 8.71~dfsg2-4
2010-08-22 22:03:08 upgrade libhal1 0.5.14-2 0.5.14-3
2010-08-22 22:03:08 upgrade libhal-storage1 0.5.14-2 0.5.14-3
2010-08-22 22:03:08 upgrade usbutils 0.86-4 0.87-5
2010-08-22 22:03:09 upgrade hal 0.5.14-2 0.5.14-3
2010-08-22 22:03:09 upgrade heirloom-mailx 12.4-1.1+b1 12.4-2
2010-08-22 22:03:10 upgrade libnspr4-0d 4.8.4-1 4.8.4-2
2010-08-22 22:03:10 upgrade xulrunner-1.9.1 1.9.1.9-6 1.9.1.11-1
2010-08-22 22:03:12 upgrade libmozjs2d 1.9.1.9-6 1.9.1.11-1
2010-08-22 22:03:12 upgrade libasound2 1.0.22-2 1.0.23-1
2010-08-22 22:03:13 upgrade libhunspell-1.2-0 1.2.8-6 1.2.11-1
2010-08-22 22:03:13 upgrade libnss3-1d 3.12.6-2 3.12.6-3
2010-08-22 22:03:13 upgrade iceweasel 3.5.9-2 3.5.11-1
2010-08-22 22:03:14 upgrade iceweasel-l10n-de 1:3.5.9+debian-1 1:3.5.11+debian-1
2010-08-22 22:03:15 upgrade im-switch 1.19 1.20
2010-08-22 22:03:16 upgrade libmagickcore3 7:6.6.0.4-2 8:6.6.0.4-2.1
2010-08-22 22:03:17 upgrade libmagickwand3 7:6.6.0.4-2 8:6.6.0.4-2.1
2010-08-22 22:03:17 upgrade imagemagick 7:6.6.0.4-2 8:6.6.0.4-2.1
2010-08-22 22:03:17 upgrade iotop 0.4-1 0.4-2
2010-08-22 22:03:18 upgrade iso-codes 3.15-1 3.19-1
2010-08-22 22:03:20 upgrade kernel-package 12.033 12.036
2010-08-22 22:03:21 upgrade libhtml-parser-perl 3.65-1 3.66-1
2010-08-22 22:03:21 upgrade libwww-perl 5.834-1 5.836-1
2010-08-22 22:03:22 upgrade libapache2-mod-perl2 2.0.4-6 2.0.4-7
2010-08-22 22:03:23 upgrade libqdbm14 1.8.74-1.4 1.8.77-3
2010-08-22 22:03:23 upgrade php5-mysql 5.3.2-1 5.3.2-2
2010-08-22 22:03:23 upgrade libpq5 8.4.3-1 8.4.4-2
2010-08-22 22:03:24 upgrade php5-pgsql 5.3.2-1 5.3.2-2
2010-08-22 22:03:24 upgrade libapache2-mod-php5 5.3.2-1 5.3.2-2
2010-08-22 22:03:25 upgrade php5-common 5.3.2-1 5.3.2-2
2010-08-22 22:03:25 upgrade libaudit0 1.7.13-1+b1 1.7.13-1+b2
2010-08-22 22:03:25 upgrade libcdt4 2.26.3-2 2.26.3-5
2010-08-22 22:03:25 upgrade libdatrie1 0.2.3-1 0.2.4-1
2010-08-22 22:03:26 upgrade libglib2.0-data 2.24.0-1 2.24.1-1
2010-08-22 22:03:27 upgrade libglide2 2002.04.10ds1-4 2002.04.10ds1-5
2010-08-22 22:03:27 upgrade libglu1-mesa 7.7.1-1 7.7.1-4
2010-08-22 22:03:27 upgrade libgraph4 2.26.3-2 2.26.3-5
2010-08-22 22:03:28 upgrade libgtk2.0-bin 2.20.0-3 2.20.1-1
2010-08-22 22:03:28 upgrade libpathplan4 2.26.3-2 2.26.3-5
2010-08-22 22:03:28 upgrade libxdot4 2.26.3-2 2.26.3-5
2010-08-22 22:03:28 upgrade libgvc5 2.26.3-2 2.26.3-5
2010-08-22 22:03:29 upgrade liblapack3gf 3.2.1-2 3.2.1-8
2010-08-22 22:03:29 upgrade librsvg2-2 2.26.2-1 2.26.3-1
2010-08-22 22:03:29 upgrade libmagickcore3-extra 7:6.6.0.4-2 8:6.6.0.4-2.1
2010-08-22 22:03:30 upgrade netpbm 2:10.0-12.1+squeeze1 2:10.0-12.2
2010-08-22 22:03:30 upgrade libnetpbm10 2:10.0-12.1+squeeze1 2:10.0-12.2
2010-08-22 22:03:31 upgrade libpaper-utils 1.1.23+nmu2 1.1.24
2010-08-22 22:03:31 upgrade libparted0debian1 2.2-5 2.3-1
2010-08-22 22:03:31 upgrade libpciaccess0 0.11.0-2 0.12.0-1
2010-08-22 22:03:31 upgrade libscim8c2a 1.4.9-2 1.4.9-5
2010-08-22 22:03:32 upgrade libsensors4-dev 1:3.1.2-2 1:3.1.2-6
2010-08-22 22:03:32 upgrade libsensors4 1:3.1.2-2 1:3.1.2-6
2010-08-22 22:03:32 upgrade libsnmp-base 5.4.2.1~dfsg-5 5.4.3~dfsg-1
2010-08-22 22:03:33 upgrade libsnmp-dev 5.4.2.1~dfsg-5+b1 5.4.3~dfsg-1
2010-08-22 22:03:33 upgrade libsnmp-perl 5.4.2.1~dfsg-5+b1 5.4.3~dfsg-1
2010-08-22 22:03:34 upgrade libsnmp15 5.4.2.1~dfsg-5+b1 5.4.3~dfsg-1
2010-08-22 22:03:35 upgrade libutempter0 1.1.5-2 1.1.5-3
2010-08-22 22:03:35 upgrade libxau-dev 1:1.0.5-2 1:1.0.6-1
2010-08-22 22:03:35 upgrade libxau6 1:1.0.5-2 1:1.0.6-1
2010-08-22 22:03:39 upgrade live-initramfs 1.177.2-1 2.0~a16-1
2010-08-22 22:03:40 upgrade live-helper 2.0~a10-1 2.0~a21-1
2010-08-22 22:03:40 upgrade debootstrap 1.0.22 1.0.23
2010-08-22 22:03:41 upgrade live-manual 20100301-1 1:2.0~a2-1
2010-08-22 22:03:41 upgrade lockfile-progs 0.1.13 0.1.15
2010-08-22 22:03:41 upgrade openssl 0.9.8n-1 0.9.8o-1
2010-08-22 22:03:42 upgrade parted 2.2-5 2.3-1
2010-08-22 22:03:42 upgrade perlmagick 7:6.6.0.4-2 8:6.6.0.4-2.1
2010-08-22 22:03:42 upgrade pm-utils 1.3.0-1 1.3.0-2
2010-08-22 22:03:44 upgrade python-distutils-extra 2.18 2.20
2010-08-22 22:03:44 upgrade python-numpy 1:1.3.0-3+b1 1:1.4.1-4
2010-08-22 22:03:46 upgrade libffi5 3.0.9-1 3.0.9-2
2010-08-22 22:03:46 upgrade python-gobject 2.21.1-1 2.21.1-2
2010-08-22 22:03:47 upgrade python-glade2 2.17.0-2 2.17.0-4
2010-08-22 22:03:47 upgrade python-gtk2 2.17.0-2 2.17.0-4
2010-08-22 22:03:48 upgrade scim 1.4.9-2 1.4.9-5
2010-08-22 22:03:49 upgrade scim-pinyin 0.5.91-1 0.5.91-1.1
2010-08-22 22:03:50 upgrade scim-chinese 0.5.91-1 0.5.91-1.1
2010-08-22 22:03:50 upgrade scim-gtk2-immodule 1.4.9-2 1.4.9-5
2010-08-22 22:03:50 upgrade scim-modules-socket 1.4.9-2 1.4.9-5
2010-08-22 22:03:50 upgrade sgml-base 1.26 1.26+nmu1
2010-08-22 22:03:51 upgrade snmpd 5.4.2.1~dfsg-5+b1 5.4.3~dfsg-1
2010-08-22 22:03:51 upgrade sudo 1.7.2p5-1 1.7.2p7-1
2010-08-22 22:05:00 upgrade syslinux-common 2:3.86+dfsg-1 2:4.02+dfsg-3
2010-08-22 22:05:01 upgrade ttf-arphic-bkai00mp 2.10-7 2.10-8
2010-08-22 22:05:02 upgrade ttf-arphic-bsmi00lp 2.10-7 2.10-8
2010-08-22 22:05:03 upgrade ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp 2.11-7 2.11-9
2010-08-22 22:05:04 upgrade ttf-arphic-gkai00mp 2.11-7 2.11-8
2010-08-22 22:05:04 upgrade update-inetd 4.36 4.37
2010-08-22 22:05:05 upgrade uuid-runtime 2.16.2-0 2.17.2-3.1
2010-08-22 22:05:05 upgrade x11-xserver-utils 7.5+1+b1 7.5+2
2010-08-22 22:05:05 upgrade xaw3dg 1.5+E-17 1.5+E-18
2010-08-22 22:05:05 upgrade xfsprogs 3.1.1 3.1.2-1
2010-08-22 22:05:06 upgrade xinit 1.2.0-1 1.2.0-2
2010-08-22 22:05:06 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-joystick 1:1.5.0-2 1:1.5.0-4
2010-08-22 22:05:06 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 1.2.1-1 1.2.2-2
2010-08-22 22:05:06 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-tslib 0.0.6-3 0.0.6-5
2010-08-22 22:05:07 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-mouse 1:1.5.0-1 1:1.5.0-2
2010-08-22 22:05:07 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse 1:12.6.5-3 1:12.6.9-2
2010-08-22 22:05:07 upgrade xserver-common 2:1.7.6-2 2:1.7.7-3
2010-08-22 22:05:07 upgrade xserver-xorg-core 2:1.7.6-2 2:1.7.7-3
2010-08-22 22:05:09 upgrade xserver-xorg-video-fbdev 1:0.4.2-1 1:0.4.2-2
2010-08-22 22:05:12 upgrade xserver-xorg-video-vesa 1:2.3.0-1 1:2.3.0-3
2010-08-22 22:05:13 upgrade xserver-xorg-video-vmware 1:11.0.1-1 1:11.0.1-2
2010-08-22 22:05:13 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-evdev 1:2.3.2-4 1:2.3.2-6
2010-08-22 22:05:13 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-wacom 0.10.3+20100109-1 0.10.5+20100416-1
2010-08-22 22:05:13 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-all 1:7.5+5 1:7.5+6
2010-08-22 22:05:14 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-void 1:1.3.0-1 1:1.3.0-2
2010-08-22 22:05:14 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-kbd 1:1.4.0-1 1:1.4.0-2
2010-08-22 22:05:14 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-aiptek 1:1.3.0-1 1:1.3.0-2
2010-08-22 22:05:14 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-acecad 1:1.4.0-1 1:1.4.0-2
2010-08-22 22:05:14 upgrade xserver-xorg-input-evtouch 0.8.8-2 0.8.8-4
2010-08-22 22:05:14 upgrade xserver-xorg 1:7.5+5 1:7.5+6
2010-08-22 22:05:15 upgrade xterm 256-1 261-1
2010-08-22 22:05:16 upgrade xorg 1:7.5+5 1:7.5+6
2010-08-22 22:05:16 upgrade fancontrol 1:3.1.2-2 1:3.1.2-6
2010-08-22 22:05:16 upgrade gs-gpl 8.71~dfsg-4 8.71~dfsg2-4
2010-08-22 22:05:16 upgrade lm-sensors 1:3.1.2-2 1:3.1.2-6
2010-08-22 22:05:16 upgrade syslog-ng 2.0.9-4.2 3.1.2-1
2010-08-22 22:05:17 upgrade user-setup 1.28 1.31
2010-08-22 22:11:48 upgrade libdevmapper1.02.1 2:1.02.48-2 2:1.02.48-3
2010-08-22 22:11:49 upgrade dmsetup 2:1.02.48-2 2:1.02.48-3
2010-08-22 22:14:11 upgrade mysql-server-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 22:16:57 upgrade mysql-server-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 22:17:39 upgrade mysql-server-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
2010-08-22 22:20:45 upgrade mysql-server-5.1 5.1.45-1 5.1.49-1
```

**Edit4**

ed solves the issue for now - but the problem still exists. It seems to be related to the init system changes.

None of these editors work in rc.S:
 * nano
 * ex
 * vi

Comment: Why would you be doing this?  Are you sure the filesystems have been remounted as read-write by the time your script is ran?  What script has a configuration file in /etc/init.d?  From my understanding of Debian policy any init script configuration file should be under /etc/default/.  Still it seems pretty odd to be modifying a configuration file as part of the startup.

Comment: Do you have a `.exrc`? (If so, try without.) Run `strace -s 9999 -o ex.strace ex ...` and see where it blocks (or whether it loops). If you don't know how to interpret the output, post them.

Comment: Oh, and of course: what was upgraded yesterday? (Look at `/var/log/dpkg.log`)

Comment: The log is very large - I can't add it. There is a lot of development going on in squeeze. I don't store configs in /etc/init.d - there is only a script trying to get configs from USB and configuring services.

Comment: Why are you executing it in a subshell? Have you tried specifying the full path to `ex` (eg. `/usr/bin/ex ...`? Does the command work from the command line? Have you considered using `sed`?

Comment: This is only an example - in this case the file might not exist - therefore it's in a subshell and it's results are redirected to /dev/null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try the alternative program 'ed' unless there is some particular feature in 'ex' that is not in 'ed'.  As you know, 'ed' has no visual mode.

Comment: Can I use ed to do this? ( ex ${PREFIX}/etc/ntp.conf -c '%s/^driftfile.*$/driftfile \/media\/bootfs\/config\/system\/ntp.drift/g' -c '/^server/d' -c '/^server/d' -c '/^server/d' -c '/^server/d' -c'wq!' ) > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: It's a different syntax - but it should work...

Answer (score 1):

Like [mpdc said](https://serverfault.com/questions/173704/using-ex-in-init-scripts/173707#173707), use `ed` instead of `ex`. Converting your script to `ed` is trivial:

```
ed -s ${PREFIX/etc/mysql/my.cnf <<ED
,s/^datadir.*$/datadir = \/usr\/local\/mysql\/data/g
wq
ED

ed -s ${PREFIX/etc/ntp.conf >/dev/null 2>&1 <<ED
,s/^driftfile.*$/driftfile \/media\/bootfs\/config\/system\/ntp.drift/g
g/^server/d
wq
ED
```

Comment: Thank you - I've already understood the minimal changes to the ex syntax. My problem is partly solved - but the question remains - what happend/changed? It seems to be keyboard related...